# That vs This in uncommon contexts

Tags: this-that

I can see the difference between "this" / "that" in most common contexts.
There are a couple of unusual ones, though, that are still pretty unclear to me.

Here are some of them:

> 1.A friend of mine is talking about some weird, violent events from his recent past. After he finishes talking, do I say:
>    "Wow, **that's** crazy"
>    or
>   "wow, **this** is crazy"?
>
> 2.I am looking at a fight scene happening in front of me. Two guys are kicking, punching each other. Do I say to my friend:
>    "Jeez, **that's** madness"
>    or
>    "Jeez, **this** is madness"?
>
> 3.Someone on TV is giving an opinion that I totally agree with.
>      Do I say:
>    "Yeah! **That's** exactly what I mean/I think"
>   or
>   "Yeah! **This** is exactly what I mean/I think"

I guess what I`m trying to figure out is when to use "that" and "this", when either:
 1.) referring to something that is happening or has happened, or
 2.) referring to what somebody has said

Comment: [1/2] I can't answer this from a strict grammatical perspective; if that's what you're seeking, you might have better luck over on our sister site, [ELL.se]. But as a native speaker, I can offer some guidance and a couple of rules of thumb: proximity and possession. Proximity is easy: if it's *here*, use *this*; if it's *there*, use *that*.

Comment: [2/2] *Possession* is definitely fuzzier for those who haven't grown up with it and developed an intuitive grasp, but: in (1) Your *friend* had the experience of the violent events; you did not. You don't *possess* the experience and the events aren't occurring *here*. So use *that*. By contrast, in (2), the fight is *here* and *both* you and your friend are experiencing it (you both possess the experience): use *this*. In (3), the newscaster is expressing an opinion: *his opinion*. The opinion is *his*, he possesses it. You agree with *that* opinion (the one *over there*, that *he has*).

Answer (score 0):

This is  a tough issue.

You may consider the advice in this reference:

> [Accessing Noun-Phrase Antecedents (RLE Linguistics B: Grammar)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=TKPIAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22that%20vs%20this%22%20grammar%20english&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xrwnVavzOMq0sAT3oIHQBg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22that%20vs%20this%22%20grammar%20english&f=false) By
>   Mira Ariel
>
> Note that in English, for example, *that* requires **identifiability by
>   both speaker and addressee**, whereas *this* sometimes refers to objects
>   **only accessible to the speaker**. [see the rest of the section]